# Hashtag Instagram scrape jupyter (return empty)

Tags: python, instagram, scrape

I'm trying to download all posts and/or comments using a certain hashtag on Instagram.

So far I had been using this code and it was working fine for me, but after a while I tried it again and it doesn't return anything. It doesn't give me any error either.
Does anyone have a way to accomplish this goal?
I would appreciate it very much, thanks a greeting!

```py
from igramscraper.instagram import Instagram
instagram = Instagram()
instagram.with_credentials('your user', 'your password')
instagram.login()

medias = instagram.get_medias_by_tag('poetry', count=20)

for media in medias:
    print(media)
    print('Account info:')
    account = media.owner
    print('Id', account.identifier)
```

Comment: I suspect you're probably running into a rate limit from the Instagram api. What is the content of `medias`? Is it empty?

Comment: Exactly, it is an empty list [].

Comment: Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/realsirjoe/instagram-scraper/blob/master/igramscraper/instagram.py) if there are no errors raised, its most likely that the tag is just not used or hasn't been used recently enough to be included in the results. Maybe try using a different more common tag that you know has had posts very recently

Comment: I have checked the hashtags issue and there really are massive hashtags but it does not catch them, I am also checking the link you have left me. Thank you very much.